# Changing the Sender's email address and name when sending an email using an Outlook object in C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have been trying to figure this one out for the last 2 days. I feel like I'm really close, but just can't get it. I've gotten my c# program to successfully send an email with all the required information in it, but I can't change the sender's name and email address. Here is my code so far:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

string emailrecipient = (Convert.ToString(txtAdmin1.Text) + "@domain.com");


            Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
            email.Recipients.Add(emailrecipient);
            email.Subject = "Your Recent Admin Rights Request";
            email.Body = "Your admin rights request has been processed. The user " + txtAdmin1.Text + " has been added as an administrator on computer " + txtName.Text + ". Please reboot your computer for these changes to take effect.";

            email.Send();
```

any advice would be amazing. I've searched all over the place, and haven't found anything that has worked so far.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to do so.  The reason I suspect this will be hard to do using the method your using to send the email is because your using Outlook to send the email.  If you simply sent an email using all code that would be different.  What purpose do you have to change who the sender's is?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sender.aspx only works if you setup multiple profiles.

Comment: I removed my attempts to make it a fresh start. I need to change it so that the email is sent from our department's shared email account, and not my personal account. I have both added in Outlook.

Comment: You really should post what you actually tried so we don't waste time talking about things that don't work.  I linked the property you need to modify.

Comment: everything that i tried didn't even compile due to incorrect syntax

Comment: I posted this in hopes that someone has done something similar, and if so if they could let me know the correct syntax to do so

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that because you are using the Outlook object model, the From property is read only (i think its called SenderName / SenderEmailAddress).

Outlook runs in the context of a specific user, so to change the user you would have to login to outlook using different credentials.

Comment: Er, not true: I can send mail from many different Outlook accounts, I've six configured at the moment in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Better change the profile name from server if you are using Interop.Outlook.dll